# python 3 utf8 output to Windows 7 console

Tags: windows, python-3.x, utf-8

I have a list of words, some of which contain unicode characters.  When I try to print this to the console, I get a `UnicodeEncodeError`:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 82-83: character maps to

If I try instead:

```
print([word.encode('utf8') for word in words])
```

The program runs successfully but my output is a list of bytes literals like:

```
[b'word1', b'word2']
```

I can't figure out a way to decode that to a string that will print on my monitor without the `b'`

Comment: The console's support for UTF-8 (codepage 65001) is disappointingly buggy. Instead use the UTF-16 (wide-character) API, either by upgrading to Python 3.6 or by installing and enabling `win_unicode_console`.

Comment: Thanks @eryksun -- what would I need to do if I wanted to used utf-16 -- via win_unicode_console -- what would the code look like to print those lists? Or are you saying I should read it in as utf-16 instead as utf-8 and then I'd be able to print it without re-encoding it?

Comment: The following replaces the `sys.std*` files with ones that use the console's wide-character API: `import win_unicode_console; win_unicode_console.enable()`. After that you would just use `print(words)` to print the repr of the list, or `print(*words, sep='\n')` if you want each word on a separate line.

Comment: Thanks @eryksun -- if you put that as a reply I'll upvote/accept it.